# Fatal error index out of range when preparing for segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, struct, indexoutofboundsexception

One out of every two times I perform the "openChat" segue, I get the error fatal error: index out of range when preparing for segue at this part:

`chatThread[((tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow as NSIndexPath?)?.row)!]`

chatThread is a reference to the ChatThread struct. I initialized it as such: `var chatThread = [ChatThread]()`

**Code**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "openChat" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? Conversation {
            print("opening conversation")
            print(destination)
            print("destinationThread")
            print(destination.chatThread)
            print("currentThread")
            print(chatThread[((tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow as NSIndexPath?)?.row)!])
            destination.chatThread = chatThread[((tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow as NSIndexPath?)?.row)!]
        }
    }
}
```

**Table view code**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let users = [PFUser.current()!.username!, self.friendStruct[indexPath.row].username!] as NSArray
    let query = PFQuery(className: "ChatThread")
    query.whereKey("users", containsAllObjectsIn: [users])
    query.getFirstObjectInBackground(block: {(object, error) -> Void in
        print("Found \(object)")
        if object != nil {
            // These users already have a thread
            let threadId = object!.objectId!
            let lockedBy = object!["lockedBy"] as? String
            let lastSender = object!["lastSender"] as! String
            let updatedAt = object!.updatedAt!
            self.chatThread.append(ChatThread(threadId: threadId, lockedBy: lockedBy, users: users, lastSender: lastSender, updatedAt: updatedAt.timeAgoDisplay2(), otherUser: self.friendStruct[indexPath.row].username!, existingConversation: true))
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if self.shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: "openChat", sender: self){
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "openChat", sender: self)
                }
            }
        }else{
            // Users never spoke
            print("users never spoke")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.chatThread.append(ChatThread(threadId: nil, lockedBy: nil, users: users, lastSender: nil, updatedAt: nil, otherUser: self.friendStruct[indexPath.row].username!, existingConversation: false))
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if self.shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: "openChat", sender: self){
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "openChat", sender: self)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your tableView functions?

Comment: Just added it @rs7

Comment: Can you also add cellForRow, numberOfRows, numberOfSections (if applicable)

Comment: The chatThread struct is only updated when selecting a cell, so it's not referred in cellForRow, numberOfRows and numberOfSections

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is because I'm missing some information. But based on what you provided me with, I would change the line showing the error (inside prepareForSegue) to this: `destination.chatThread = chatThread.last` . The reason being, you are appending the thread to the chatThread array before performSegue, so the last element of the array is what you want to pass in.

Comment: Wow that seems to have done it!

Comment: Thank you @rs7 !

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score -1):

Solution from @rs7. Simply change `chatThread[((tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow as NSIndexPath?)?.row)!]` to `chatThread.last` fixed the problem.

**Working code**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "openChat" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? Conversation {
            destination.chatThread = chatThread.last
        }
    }
}
```